# Does SQLAlchemy Differentiate Between Tables and Views?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

Does SQLAlchemy see tables and views as the same? If not, how would I tell SQLAlchemy that a database object is a view rather than a table? I could not find this anywhere in SQLAlchemy's documentation or online.

Comment: A couple of links, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766940/how-to-create-an-sql-view-with-sqlalchemy) is for version 0.7 but I think it still applies since this [faq list](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/metadata_schema.html#does-sqlalchemy-support-alter-table-create-view-create-trigger-schema-upgrade-functionality) states it is still not supported. Hope it helps.

Comment: I think the linked question in the previous comment plus [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2027143/3079302) answer your question.